# How does git handle multiple pull requests that rely on eachother?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull, pull-request

G'day,

Should be an easy question to answer.

So I have been working on my own branch of some code, and i'm ready to send a pull request to merge it to master.

Problem is, I merged another branch while I was working on the code, and that branch hasn't been merged into 'master' yet.

There's a pull request in the works though - So my question is:

If I were to send a pull request, how would git handle this? Will it recognize that my pull request is 3rd in the list and therefore 'prefer' the changes from the first 2 requests before adding my code or is this something that the project owner needs to be aware of, in which case i could just add a note in my pull request that pull requests 1 and 2 should be merged before mine?

Comment: `I merged another branch while I was working on the code`

Are the commits from the branch you depend on in your branch? If you merged, they should be now. If your branch gets merged into master, the commits you took from the other pull request should be also.

Quick note: Pull Requests are a feature of GitHub, not git itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of the repo can select and apply the pull requests in the order they want, so its up to them. Once they do, the resulting merge will happen and include the code that you merged into your branch from another, so unless you still have some other dependency on that other branch, you should be OK. If you do have some dependency, then when you submit your pull request, you can add a comment to say such.

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question. I'd thought it would work in this way but wanted to confirm it before going ahead :)

Comment: Can't yet, sorry. Too new to stackoverflow so i haven't got the rep.

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought as the originator of the question, you could mark it as answered, but maybe not.